# My App is not working in Android 8, below is the stack trace we are getting in Android studio,

Tags: android, sencha-touch, android-8.0-oreo

```
 3053-3135/? E/﹕ Couldn't opendir /data/app/vmdl1653487319.tmp: No such file or directory

 3053-3135/? E/installd﹕ Failed to delete /data/app/vmdl1653487319.tmp: No such file or directory

 6865-6865/? E/Finsky﹕ [2] com.google.android.finsky.wear.bl.a(3): onConnectionFailed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null, message=null}

 4361-4361/? E//system/bin/webview_zygote32﹕ failed to make and chown /acct/uid_99069: Permission denied

 4361-4361/? E/Zygote﹕ createProcessGroup(99069, 0) failed: Permission denied

 4387-4387/? E/asset﹕ setgid: Operation not permitted

 4296-4296/? E/PushMessage﹕ token..title:: null

 6008-6008/? E/NetworkScheduler.ATC﹕ Received callback from client for task that is already complete. 
ComponentInfo{com.google.android.inputmethod.latin/com.firebase.jobdispatcher.GooglePlayReceiver} task_check_update

 3526-3543/? E/BatteryStatsService﹕ no controller energy info supplied

 4296-4296/? E/PushMessage﹕ token..title:: fi8UxsDCdu0:APA91bGW6JEoNm-CZqemOBu_FiZ4YYAkfxCYGTyENFs8nXXBanCe_qyGhXL2hDR8_38SDeyghkbn_B3uaA_n6LpIqQsX2jFvOYXP8LDYDMLu2WSYtj2cj6A0pAi12-KxPMOgBhHOH5Mn

 6008-2635/? E/ctxmgr﹕ [ProducerStatusImpl]updateStateForNewContextData: inactive, contextName=7

 6008-6008/? E/ctxmgr﹕ [PlaceFenceHelper]NearbyBuffer is null!

6317-30075/? E/SQLiteCastStore﹕ End saving paired guest mode devices

3526-11492/? E/BatteryStatsService﹕ no controller energy info supplied

 6008-6008/? E/ctxmgr﹕ [WorkInfo]Attribution was already enqueued pkg=com.google.android.gms, lbl=PlacesProducer_receive, start=unspec, stop=unspec.

 6008-2635/? E/ctxmgr﹕ [WorkManager]Ongoing task not found: PlacesProducer_receive

 3526-3542/? E/zygote64﹕ failed to kill 1 processes for processgroup 3624

   356-356/? E/SELinux﹕ avc:  denied  { find } for interface=android.hardware.memtrack::IMemtrack pid=4585 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_25:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:hal_memtrack_hwservice:s0 tclass=hwservice_manager

 6008-2635/? E/ctxmgr﹕ [ProducerStatusImpl]updateStateForNewContextData: inactive, contextName=7

 6008-6008/? E/ctxmgr﹕ [PlaceFenceHelper]NearbyBuffer is null!

 3526-3683/? E/ConnectivityService﹕ RemoteException caught trying to send a callback msg for NetworkRequest [ LISTEN id=161, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&FOREGROUND] ]

 3772-3785/? E/RecentsTaskLoader﹕ Unexpected null component name or activity info: ComponentInfo{com.cbq.CBMobile/com.cbq.CBMobile.CBQMainActivity}, null

 6865-6865/? E/Finsky﹕ [2] com.google.android.finsky.wear.bl.a(3): onConnectionFailed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null, message=null}

 5024-5024/? E/asset﹕ setgid: Operation not permitted

 3053-3603/? E/﹕ Couldn't opendir /data/app/vmdl447807582.tmp: No such file or directory

 3053-3603/? E/installd﹕ Failed to delete /data/app/vmdl447807582.tmp: No such file or directory

 6865-6865/? E/Finsky﹕ [2] com.google.android.finsky.wear.bl.a(3): onConnectionFailed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null, message=null}

 5100-5100/? E//system/bin/webview_zygote32﹕ failed to make and chown /acct/uid_99070: Permission denied

 5100-5100/? E/Zygote﹕ createProcessGroup(99070, 0) failed: Permission denied

 5128-5128/? E/asset﹕ setgid: Operation not permitted

 5069-5069/? E/PushMessage﹕ token..title:: null

 3526-3543/? E/BatteryStatsService﹕ no controller energy info supplied
```

Comment: You may want to copy the exact error code, the stack trace include non error logs from the logcat, this will help figure out what the problem is. Also, you may want to check if you app is violating one of the newest Android 8 specs.

Comment: OP, please, don't make it a list, please for the love of god if you have mercy put the trace as code and dont' make us see such a thing please

Comment: Just put it like code not a list.

Comment: I'm getting the exact same error too and only in Android Oreo. I suspect it is related to an Glide issue? Are you using the Glide image loading library in your app? Here is the Glide issue I opened. https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/2724